# Manage bulk imports

Tags: sql-server, import

How do I set up a rule for my bulk imports, so that if today's import fails, SQL Server will prevent future imports until the issue is resolved?

I'm using bulk insert code. The code is calling the file path from a specific folder to into a SQL Server table. The process is run from a SQL Server job that runs once a day

Comment: How are you doing bulk import?  Source, destination, what method being used?

Comment: A SQL Server job that runs once a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this really the best option?**

First: you should assess whether you should really stop the job, or simply move the failed file out of the way and keep going.

This is going to depend on what you're importing. If you're importing data that must be processed in the order received (think restoring a database to a point in time with transaction logs backups), then it makes sense to stop the process. If it's a full refresh of a data set, then there's no reason to pause - if the next file is processed successfully before the current file's problem can be fixed, it shouldn't really matter.

Even if the data seems to logically build on what's gone before, ask if that has to be the case.

I've dealt with a process that ran 6am to 11PM seven days a week. If the records in the file did not already exist, they were added; otherwise, existing records were updated. The table included a `last_modified_time`. Each file would only have a few records to consider (usually 1-3, sometimes as many as 12). When a file failed, we moved it to a "Failed" directory, sent out a message, and went on with the next file. When we processed the failed files, we did so manually. We'd look for each record; if it was already there, and its `last_modified_time` was newer than the file in question, we removed it from the file (either a later, more-up-to-date version was processed successfully in a later file, or someone manually entered the data; in either case, the data in the system is more recent than what we had, so we could ignore the "bad" record). Any remaining records were run back through the process (fixing whatever caused them to fail in the first place, of course).

In our case, new files were uploaded every 2 minutes. We didn't have a 24-7 support staff, just two people; if the process has stopped every time it failed, we might have had thousands of records waiting to be processed (did I mention these were sales?); this would have been problematic. By moving on, we would have 3-4 sales waiting for us to fix a problem, not thousands.

**If it is....**

That said: if you *really* need to stop processing the job, your best bet is some sort of a flag. I would create a new table in your database, `job_flag` or something like that, with two columns: one would have a unique identifier for the job (or group of jobs, if necessary) that needs to be stopped, the other column (let's say `stop_job`, type `char(1)`) would indicate if the job should run (`stop_job = 'F'`) or be stopped (`stop_job = 'T'`).

Add a new first step to your job: a T_SQL step like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM job_flag
            WHERE job_name = 'Job To Stop'
              AND stop_job = 'F')
    SELECT 1;
ELSE
    SELECT 1/0;
```

So, this step succeeds if the flag is present and says not to stop the job, and fails if it's absent or if it's present but says to stop the job.

Have the "On Success" action for the job step take you to your normal processing; have the "On Failure" action take you to steps that do whatever you want when your job is stopped: send an e-mail message that the job didn't run because it was flagged, or whatever is appropriate. For the final step of this chain, quit with failure or success, whichever you like (the job did not technically fail, after all; it did exactly what it was supposed to do; still since a failure lead to this, you might want to continue to fail the job).

Back in the normal processing chain, run your existing process. However, if any step fails such that the job should not be run next time, have the "On Failure" action update the `job_flag` record for the job, so that `stop_job = 'T'`. Then, continue with whatever else you do when the job fails.

I'm assuming that someone will manually need to resolve the problem. If so, that person can manually update the `job_flag` record so the job will run again; or, you can create a job (with no schedule) or a stored procedure to do this for them, if more appropriate. If there is some automated process that can resolve the problem, add a step to the process to set `stop_job = 'F'` for that job when all is good.